# Recover undected existing partitions

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, restore

Is there anyway of restoring the partitions? They exist and have all data inside (test it with **testdisk**), they are three (1 linux 2 NTFS). The disk shows as unallocated/not initialized.

I'd like to do so, so I won't have to restore the disk by writing 0 to it and build it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it is a quite risky operation, because it is almost impossible to recover them automatically. Nobody and no tool could guarantee that you wouldn't lose all your data.  You'd better recover all your data to another HDD using recovery software like [R-Studio](http://www.r-studio.com/) or EasyRecovery, DataRecovery etc.

However if you still want to try and recover existing partitions:

1. You need to determine the start and end points of your partitions using DataRecovery for example.
2. Use WinHex - Physical Disc - Alt+F12 - Master Boot Record - Apply.
3. Edit the data, Enter, close the window, Ctrl+S.

Be careful and good luck.

Comment: tnx for the info, I will have it in mind... but I had decided to recover the important data and rebuild the disk